# The equivalent relation of definition of Affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

According to Hartshorne's textbook, the definition of an **affine scheme** is a locally ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_{x})$ which is isomorphic (as a locally ringed space) to the spectrum of some ring. More precisely, there exists a ring R such that,

> i) $f: X \to \operatorname{Spec} R $  : homeomorphism
>
> ii)  $f^{\sharp} : \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} R} \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{X}$ : isomorphism (where $f_* \mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Xf^{-1})$

However, in comparison to Hartshorne's textbook, according to the following [PDF](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Ullery.pdf),

Let the topological space $X$ along with the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ be a locally ringed space, where $\mathcal{O}_X(X)=R$. Then $X$ along with its sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$, which we will denote $(X,\mathcal{O}_{x})$, is an **affine scheme** if it is isomorphic to $(\operatorname{Spec} R,\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} R})$, which is true when the following conditions hold :

> i)  $X$ and $\operatorname{Spec} R$ are homeomorphic as topological spaces
>
> ii') $\mathcal{O}_X(X_f)=R_f$
>   (where $X_f = \operatorname{Spec} R - V(f)$, $R_f$ is the localization $R$ at $f$ )

My question is whether the condition ii) on Hartshorne's textbook is equivalent to ii)' on the definition on the [PDF](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Ullery.pdf)

Comment: Both condition $(ii)$ and $(ii')$ only make sense if we assume condition $(i)$. So if you believe that $(i)+(ii)$ and $(i)+(ii')$ are both equivalent to $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ being affine, then yes, $(ii)$ and $(ii')$ must be equivalent.

Comment: The second definition is a little sloppy in that the equality in equation ii is not just arbitrary isomorphism but needs to be induced by the homeomorphism in (i). Given this, the question boils down to whether (ii') implies (ii) in the condition of (i).